# Apache Kafka Multiple Producer to a Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, system.reactive

I have an application that is currently running and is using Rx Streams to move data between different sources. Now in this application, I have a couple of streams whose messages I would like to write to a single Kafka topic. In practice, say I have Streams 1 to 5 as below:

Stream1 - Takes in DataType A
Stream2 - Takes in DataType B and so on

Where these Streams1 to Streams5 are Rx Observers, each observing for a different type of data. All these data types that I get out of the stream are converted to a common JSON structure. I want this JSON structure to be pushed to a single Kafka topic.

Now the questions are:

1. Should I create one KafkaProducer for each of those Streams or rather Rx Observer instances?
2. What happens if multiple threads using its own instance of a KafkaProducer to write to the same topic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many producers to create in kafka?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376715/how-many-producers-to-create-in-kafka)

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445308/kafka-multiple-producer-writing-to-same-topic-ordering-of-message-and-data-bur

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: I can't because there is a lot of code to be shown. But what I have explained is exactly what happens and I would like to know if I would hit any  potential problems with using multiple KafkaProducer instances to write to a  single Topic with just one partition.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? You'll hit a performance bottleneck at some point, but otherwise having many producers writing to a single topic/partition is no big deal.

Comment: What do you mean by "hit a performance bottleneck at some point"? Could you bolster your argument with some practical justification?